# Do we need to put the same if condition in both new/create & edit/update in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If we want to put an `if` condition in Rails action `new` or `edit`. Do we need to put the same `if` condition in `create/update` as well to enforce the rule? What concerns us is that a user will make up a html page and submit directly to server for create or update. Here is the example

```
def new
  if condition1
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  if condition1
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Our question is in `def create` or `def update`, do we need to apply the same `if` condition again so a user can not submit a make-up page directly to server for create or update? Here is the sudo code:

```
def create
  if condition1
    do create
  end
end

def update
  if condition1
    do update
  end
end
```

OR we don't have to put the `if` condition in `create/update` and a user will not be able to submit a make-up html page directly to the server.

Comment: users can submit whatever they want, whenever they want. Its up to you to prevent them from doing things you don't want them to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, as in if you examine a scaffold, `def new` is used simply for `@model = Model.new` in order to declare a `Model` object. Obviously, I don't know the implications of your project, however this declaring doesn't have many side-effects (meaning it doesn't actually create a new Model object).

What I'm trying to say is, therefore, you may ONLY need to put the condition in the `def create` and `def update` as those are usually the methods that actually `save` the Object to the database.

And yes, as @sevenseacat mentioned, if the route is defined, the user does not necessarily need a button or link to create, so it is your job, as the developer, to prevent unwanted creations.

Answer (score 1):

Some user can submit malicious forms and requests to your server. The good thing is: you can intercept these requests in your controller and avoid the malicious code into your model/database.

For example, in Rails 3 you have the `attr_accessible` method to allow the attributes that you will allow to be submitted from your form. All other attributes will be ignored. So using `attr_accessible` prevents a lot of damage and make-up forms being submitted to your form. This way you don't need to repeat yourself everytime (using if conditions to prevent damage data to be submitted).

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :nickname
end
```

Another feature very helpful is [model validation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). Validations are used to ensure that only valid data is saved into your database. Then you can use hooks like:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

So in case someone tries to pass:

```
Person.create(name: nil)
```

It will return false and will not save the object in the DB. Then you can detect that in your controller and redirect to an error page or whatever.

Comment: attr_accessible and validates have been implemented in the app.

Comment: So if you filter the attributes the user can send to your server, I wonder what kind of validation are you doing with an if that can't be accomplished using those features. Because that avoids a lot of if/else code and makes your code more DRY.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to check if user is eligible to perform creation.

In the simplest case, yes you want to have if statements in both new and create to check the user.

However, you can DRY it by using `before_action`

```
before_action :check, only:[:new,:create]

def check
  if ! condition1
    head :bad_request
  end
end
```

Then again, if my guess is right and you really want to do user authorization, then it is better to use a gem like Cancan to define all these checking elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, there is user authorization before each action. Sometime the record needs to locked. For example, the record is being reviewed.

Comment: Then learning https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan will be really helpful for this question.